# Toggling variable between jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I've seen questions like this on this board, but none that exactly matches my situation, so please don't mark me down until you've read my problem.

I have a table. Each th of the table has an id that matches a field in a mysql database. When you click the th, I want to conduct a query of the database with an order by direction of desc. If you click the same field again, I want the query to have an order by direction of asc.

The problem is maintaining the value of the direction across states. So far, the direction isn't changing when I click the table header.

Can anyone give me an idea please of what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});

function loadData(orderby) {
    $.ajax({         
        url: 'display.php',         
        type: "POST",         
        data: ({orderby: orderby, direction: 'desc'}),         
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#content").hide();       
            $("#content").html(data);         
            $("#content").show();
            $('th').click(function(){
                    var orderby = $(this).attr('id');
                    loadData(orderby);
            });
        }     
    }); 
 }
```

PHP:

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if(isset($by) and $by==" ASC"){
    $by=" DESC";
}else{
    $by=" ASC";
}

if (isset($_POST["orderby"])) {
    $orderby = $_POST["orderby"];
    //echo $orderby;
}

//build a query on the database
$q = "Select * from uncompensated";
if (isset($_POST["orderby"])) {
    $q .= " order by " . $orderby;
} else {
    $q .= ' order by year2013';
}
if (isset($by)) {
    $q .= $by;
    echo $q;
} else {
    $by = ' DESC';
    $q .= $by;
    echo $q;
}

//echo $q;
$result = $db->query($q);

echo "<table cellspacing='0' >";
echo "<tr id='header'><th id='Name'>Name</th><th id='year2013'>2013</th><th id='year2012'>2012</th><th id='year2011'>2011</th><th id='year2010'>2010</th><th id='year2009'>2009</th><th id='year2008'>2008</th><th id='year2007'>2007</th><th id='year2006'>2006</th><th id='year2005'>2005</th><th id='year2004'>2004</th><th id='year2003note'>* 2003</th><th id='year2002'>2002</th><th id='year2001'>2001</th><th id='year2000'>2000</th><th id='year1999'>1999</th><th id='year1998'>1998</th><th id='year1997'>1997</th></tr>";
 while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    (code)
}
```

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you don't seem to be changing what your click does. if the page gets build with `sortBy('asc')`, then that's all you'll ever do - sort by asc. you need to change the link, or keep the direction in a separate variable. `var last_sort = 'asc'; function toggleSort() { if (last_sort == 'asc') { last_sort='desc' }` kinda thing.

Comment: @Marc B: forget the sql injection for now. I am toggling - if (isset($by)) { $q .= $by; } else { $by = ' DESC'; $q .= $by; }

Comment: One issue lies in your AJAX data object. You've hard-coded "desc"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I rewrote this line: data: ({orderby: orderby, direction: 'desc'}),   to say data: ({orderby: orderby}),  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: By removing the "direction" your PHP script will never know what direction to use for the SQL. In jQuery you need to dynamically set the direction by listening for clicks on the table header

Comment: I'm using a session variable and it's working now.